# Year range to date time format

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, data-analysis

Currently I have a series of string as a column in pandas dataframe which represents a particular year in a "yyyy-yyyy" format for example "2004-2005" is a single **string** value in this column.

I wanted to know if there is anyway to convert this from **string** to something similar to **datetime** format.

The purpose for this is to calculate the difference between the values of this column and other similar column in "Years". For example something similar to below:

```
col 1        col2        Answer(Total years)
2004-2005    2006-2007    3
```

Note: One of the ways I thought of doing was to make a dictionary mapping each year to a unique integer value and then calculate the difference between them.

Although I was wondering if there is any simpler way of doing it.

Comment: This is more tricky than your example, as there are a few corner cases:
1.  A gap in dates (e.g. col1 = '2004-2005' and col2 = '2007-2009')
2.  Partial overlap (e.g. col1 = '2004-2005' and col2 = '2005-2009')
3.  Total overlap (e.g. col1 = '2004-2005' and col2 = '2003-2009') What is the expected result for each of these cases?

Comment: can you provide more rows? Is the object to subtract the first year in col1 form the last year in col2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you subtracting the last year in column 2 with the first year in column 1. In which case I'd use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract.html) (and [convert the result to a number](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html)):

```
In [11]: pd.to_numeric(df['col 1'].str.extract('(\d{4})'))
Out[11]:
0    2004
Name: col 1, dtype: int64

In [12]: pd.to_numeric(df['col2'].str.extract('-(\d{4})')) - pd.to_numeric(df['col 1'].str.extract('(\d{4})'))
Out[12]:
0    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "something similar to a datetime object." Datetimes aren't designed to represent date ranges.

If you want to create a pair of datetime objects you could do something like this:

```
[datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y') for x in '2005-2006'.split('-')]
```

Alternatively you could try using a Pandas `date_range` object if that's closer to what you want.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.date_range.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find the difference between the lowest year and the highest year, here is a go at it

```
col1="2004-2005"
col2="2006-2007"
col1=col1.split("-") # make a list of the years in col1 ['2004', '2005']
col2=col2.split("-") # make a list of the years in col2 ['2006', '2007']
biglist=col1+col2 #add the two list
biglist.sort() #sort the list from lowest year to highest year
Answer=int(biglist[len(biglist)-1])-int(biglist[0]) #find the difference between lowest and highest year
```